# Best way to have script urls in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting

I am developing my own theme for private use and i have a lot of scripts working with urls with extra parameters.

I'm finding my self adding a lot of empty pages to my site just to be able to connect some php file to specific url so i will be able to send parameters to that specific address.

Is there a better way i can have urls that can be associated with specific php files without adding pages or other things to the site. just like work out of the box when installing my theme?

Comment: Do you want to control which template is displayed with the url parameters? Or what are you trying to do with the parameters?

Comment: Not really. just use some php file to process stuff. the front user isn't suppose to use those urls.

Comment: In that case, I would just use the theme's `functions.php` file. That file is automatically included by WordPress, and in that I would require the other php files as needed based on the url parameters.

Comment: Yes, but i need a url to send parameters to those scripts. also i don't want them to load on every page load with the all functions file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this code:

```
//page url: http://www.example/myurl

add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    //wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myurl.php
    add_rewrite_rule('myurl/$', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myplugin/myurl.php', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
```

**More info**:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: That seams great. so if i want for example domain.com/myurl/ to activate a php file test.php that is in my theme root folder. would this work: add_rewrite_rule('myurl/$', get_template_directory() . 'test.php'); ?

Comment: Also - can it mess my other custom types urls or other stuff i need to worry about?

Comment: Use this: `add_rewrite_rule('myurl/$', get_template_directory() . '/test.php');`

Comment: Thanks. it doesn't seam to work for me. any ideas what can go wrong or what tests can i make to get a direction?

Comment: am i suppose to see something changing in the htaccess file?